# How to prevent creation of development.sqlite3 file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I changed my `database.yml` file to use `postgresql` instead of `sqlite3`.
But when I do `rake db:migrate` - `development.sqlite3` file gets created.

Here's my `database.yml` file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: scrumban_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: scrumban_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: scrumban_production
  username: scrumban
  password: <%= ENV['scrumban_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include the sqlite3 gem and it should stop creating it.

Comment: sqlite3 gem is deleted from my Gemfile. Also it is not presented in Gemfile.lock file as well. After removing this gem I did a "bundle" command. It did not help.

Comment: I noticed that Webrick webserver was running. After I stopped it and started again - problem has disappeared!